# multiple length/height/width calculator

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Hi I would like to know how I would go about doing something similar to the link below, if you click on any of the T shaped designs, its just step one T shape I need?

https://www.premierrange.co.uk/shaping-designer?model=splashback&type=search

I need it so when you put a measurement in, it changes the size of the shape on the screen

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I haven't tried anything as of yet.  I was thinking of looking at Canvas Draw Path?

Comment: The Dojotoolkit API is well complete to do this kind of thing
https://dojotoolkit.org/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about it:

The example you gave is a simple SVG figure/image where the height and width are updated with JS. That's not the hard part. But the whole thing in itself is a bit more complicated...

I'm assuming that when a user create a pattern he has to be able to sent you the data somehow. that means that you're looking at some sort of form. so what I would probably do is:

**First**, create the svg width height system.

**Second**, you should create hidden form inputs that update and the same time the width and height are updated.

**Third**, Create the rest of the form, link up everything and you're done.

Hope this will help